# Google Pie Chart does not display properly the slices

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization, pie-chart

As you can see in the following image I have many pie charts in my webpage and they do not fill completely the container (generally only an half is filled or LESS):

[image: Google Visualization API - Pie Chart Visualization Problem]

Here some code:

```
        var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Tipo', 'Valore'],
            ['Recapitate', sent],
            ['Ritornate/Bloccate', errors]
        ]);

        options1 = {
            width: 250,
            height: 250,
            pieHole: 0.5,
            colors: ['#06dd00','#e12a00'],
            legend: {position: 'none'},
            pieSliceText: 'none',
            tooltip: {textStyle: {color: '#333', fontName: 'Arial', fontSize: 16}},
            chartArea:{left: 0,top: 0,width: "100%",height: "100%"},
            enableInteractivity: false/*,
            animation: { duration: 1000, easing: 'out' }*/
        };

        chart1 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('grafico-inviate'));
        chart1.draw(data1, options1);

        var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Tipo', 'Valore'],
            ['Aperte', unique_opened],
            ['Non aperte', combined1]
        ]);

        options2 = {
            width: 250,
            height: 250,
            pieHole: 0.5,
            colors: ['#3e9ca8','#ff5932'],
            legend: {position: 'none'},
            pieSliceText: 'none',
            tooltip: {textStyle: {color: '#333', fontName: 'Arial', fontSize: 16}},
            chartArea:{left: 0,top: 0,width: "100%",height: "100%"},
            enableInteractivity: false/*,
            animation: { duration: 1000, easing: 'out' }*/
        };

        chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('grafico-aperte'));
        chart2.draw(data2, options2);
```

The problem arises independently from the OS/Web-Browser.
I do not know if this is a bug of the visualization API or am I missing something?

**SOLVED!!:**

Do not ask me why but if i put the data in the following way (using the javascript `Number()` function) it works:

```
        var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Tipo', 'Valore'],
            ['Aperte', Number(unique_opened)],
            ['Non aperte', Number(combined1)]
        ]);
```

Comment: Can you show your complete file with hmml markup and styling?

Comment: Most probably you did not provide enough space for charts. With your code and defining missing variables I got both pie charts.

Comment: One question: In console, if you drill down your elements you will reach `svg` element for one of the pies. Each `<svg>...</svg>` pair is definition of one piechart. If you just cut&paste one svg markup to separte html page into body section, what you will get? Whole pie or half pie?

Comment: BTW: did you use `pieStartAngle` option for those two piecharts shown?

Comment: If I copy the <svg>...</svg> pair definition to a separate html page I still get an half pie.

Comment: I did not use pieStartAngle for the charts

Comment: That's interesting regarding <svg>. So you somehow produce that markup and size or some other styling has no influence. I asked about `pieStartAngle` because it looks like chart was rotated back exactly half of angle of smaller part.

Comment: FYI, the conversion to a `Number` is necessary if your variables contain strings, as the Visualization API treats numbers and strings very differently (and produces some odd effects when you try to use strings for numbers, as you have seen with your PieCharts).

Comment: If numbers are ok, then I see one possibiilty, but that is just guess. Your picture has containter `chart-container-1`. Thas is not used in code provided. You can produce half pie chart setting 50% to white and  using half value of others. So instead of two values, you use 3, one is faked and it is 50% and is white. Legend for that pie-chart is 'manually' produced.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is your case but you can produce such semicircle in the following way. Your code little changed (only second part):

```
var unique_opened = 5.555; // real value: 11.11;
var combined1 = 44.445;  //   real value: 88.89;
var noshow = 50;

....
    var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Tipo', 'Valore'],
        ['Aperte', unique_opened],
        ['Non aperte', combined1],
        ['noshow', noshow]
    ]);

    options2 = {
        width: 250,
        height: 250,
        pieHole: 0.5,
        colors: ['#3e9ca8','#ff5932', '#ffffff'],
    ...
```

And you get:

[image]

Idea of [Javier González](http://gonzo.teoriza.com/truco-para-conseguir-el-grafico-semicirculo-con-google-charts)